# Pasting unfiltered data next to filtered data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I know there must be a way of achieving this without writing a macro, and just doing a straight paste.

I have two columns (Column A and Column B) that contain 10 records. 5 records are filtered out; so, currently, only 5 records are visible. Now I have another column with 5 records on a separate sheet that is unfiltered. I want to copy those 5 records, and paste the data in Column C next to filtered data.

Excel pastes all 5 records, but some of the 5 records are not visible because they are in rows that have been filtered out.

How can I simply paste the 5 records, so to insert only into the rows that are currently visible without using a macro or a vlookup? I am using Excel 2008, although it shouldn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem there is any built-in Excel functionality to do this. Your only recourse will be writing a VBA routine to paste into visible cells.

Comment: Can you provide a VBA code to use?