# How to copy a bunch of data into a filtered table in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/261011/pasting-unfiltered-data-next-to-filtered-data-in-excel?rq=1) question which is from 2011, and i am asking assuming that someone has found a workaround for this issue in the last 10 years.

I have a gigantic table, in which i have to paste data. But the data is only ment for a subsection of the table, which i get when filtering the table for one column. The source of the data is just a plain unfiltered Excel sheet where i copy the column from.

Surely there must be a way to simply Ctrl+V the data into only the VISIBLE cells i am currently seeing from my filter, without using Macros or VBA scripts?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804297/how-to-find-same-text-in-excel-with-formula) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method with formulas in this article:

https://spreadsheetplanet.com/paste-filtered-column-skipping-hidden-cells/